# How to divide line of text that has both text and numbers with $ sign in front of it?

Tags: vb.net

I want to divide this array of texts into 3 divisions

SAMPLE TEXT:

> Personal injury during holiday $10,000
>   Property damage $100,000
>   Car damage $10,000 for third party
>   Property damage $100,000 for properties located in the City area
>   $20,000 each and every policy

And it should be organized like this:

- Division 1 - full text before numbers
- Division 2 - Numbers, it always starts with $
- Division 3 - full text after numbers

**Note:**
The number of words before and after the number is inconsistent. Only the `$` sign is consistent.

Comment: if you share your existing code and where you're stuck, you'll get help much quickly

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you don't explain what behaviour you're  getting and what errors you get and on what line they occur. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks

Comment: would you like to split the text into an array or a list?  If so how would you like to access those values?

Comment: Inlcude example output

Comment: Thank you all, I will provide more details in my next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, The code might look complex but by studying it you will understand it

```
 Dim test As String = "your string here"
 'Split the text into lines and store in array
 Dim split1() As String = Split(test, vbLf)

 Dim split2() As String
 Dim split3() As String
 For x As Integer = 0 To Ubound(split1) - 1
     split2 = Split(split1(x))
     For y As Integer = 0 To Ubound(split2) - 1
         If split2(y).StartsWith("$") Then
             For z As Integer = 0 To y - 1
                 split3(0) &= split2(z)
             Next
             split3(1) = split2(y)
             If y < Ubound(split2) - 1 Then
                  For a As Integer = y + 1 To Ubound(split2) - 1
                       split3(2) &= split2(y)
                  Next
             End If
         End If
         For b As Integer = 0 To 2
            Console.WriteLine(split3(x)) 
            ' or you could use Textbox.Text += split3(x)
            ' Do whatever you want with those values here
            'split3(0)  = Text before $ sign
            'split3(1)  = Text with $ sign
            'split3(2) = Text after $ sign
         Next

     Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is ideal for this. I will show an example for one line but you can apply it to every line in a loop.

```
Dim str = "Car damage $10,000 for third party"

'Create regex which matches three groups:
'Group 1: (.*)       ==> matches any characters
'Group 2: (\$[\d,]+) ==> matches $ followed by one or more digits and/or comma (,)
'Group 3: (.*)       ==> matches any characters
Dim regex = New Regex("(.*)(\$[\d,]+)(.*)")

Dim match = regex.Match(str)

'Get values for all groups, skipping the first one which matches the whole string.
Dim parts = match.Groups.Cast(Of Group).Skip(1).Select(Function(g) g.Value).ToArray()
```

You get this array as a result:

[image]